# Executing Makefile recipe once after optional intermediate recipes

Tags: makefile

A given tool compiles all of the source files in a folder and I'm trying to come up with a Makefile to build only the stale objects.

My first result was:

```
objects := a.bin b.bin c.bin

all: $(objects) compile

%.bin: %.src
    @echo copy $< to build/ folder

compile:
    @echo run compiler against the build/ folder
```

which has the following shortcomings:

- the `compile` recipe is always executed with `make all`, even when there's nothing to build, which I could workaround by conditionally run the compiler, depending on whether the build directory is empty;
- specifying a target `make a.bin` doesn't execute the `compile` recipe.

The above led me to this second attempt:

```
objects := a.bin b.bin c.bin

all: $(objects)

build/%.src: %.src
    @echo copy $< to build/ folder

compile: build/a.src build/b.src build/c.src
    @echo run compiler against the build/ folder

%.bin: %.src build/%.src compile
    @echo $@ is outdated

.INTERMEDIATE: compile build/a.src build/b.src build/c.src
```

Specifying all of the `build/*.src` prerequisites for the `compile` target is the only way I managed to ensure the copying occurs before the compilation. 
Unfortunately it also means that *all* of the sources get copied to the build directory, even when it is not needed, which makes the compiler build everything, nullifying the purpose of having a Makefile in the first place.

Marking `compile` as intermediate produces the wanted effect to skip compilation when all of the `.bin` objects are up-to-date.
The remaining intermediate prerequisites seem to produce no effect, though.

I suspect `.SECONDEXPANSION` or a recursive call to `$(MAKE)` may be the way to go, is there any more elegant solution?

I'll need to run it on Windows, so a solution which is compatible with GNU Make 3.81 is preferred, but I'd be anyway satisfied with understanding how it could possibly work with any newer release which is not that quirky.

Comment: What exactly does the compiler do? Does it read source files in the working directory and write binary files in `build/`? Does it compile every source file it finds, or can you give it a list of sources? Or a list of binaries?

Comment: @Beta, it compiles every source file it finds in the build directory and outputs the binary in the working dir, so in case you have `build/{a,b,c}.src`, `compiler build/` writes `./{a,b,c}.bin`.
You cannot pass it specific source files, such as `compiler build/c.src`.

Comment: The "compiler" you're using sounds like the antithesis of any reasonable build/make system -- why rebuild all targets when none of the dependencies have changed?  What does it do that couldn't be replicated with a simple makefile rule?

Comment: @G.M., indeed I give the build automation tool, not the compiler, the responsibility to choose the targets - does gcc have an understanding of which deps have changed? Nonetheless this compiler is old, closed-source and far from ideal, I agree, we could even come up with alternative workarounds such as moving each source to its folder, but I'm more interested in exploring and understanding make's possibilities.

Comment: You are saying that you want "build only the stale objects". But you can't - if you run your compiler, it will build all the sources. Maybe, if any objects is stale, you want to run the compiler (which will rebuild all the objects) - is this what you really want??

Answer (score 0):

See my comment: I will answer what I think you really want. Please correct me if that is not what you really want.

I don't understand why you need `/build` directory at all - from your question, there is no need. Is there some other need for it?

In any case, copying files around is a very bad idea. If you must, use symlinks.

Last comment, In My Humble Opinion, you are trying to solve a simple problem with increasingly needlessly complicated solutions.  You should try to practice finding simple solutions.

OK, here is a "canonical" solution to such a problem. It singles out one target file and separates it from the rest. (If there is only one file, it will still work, because the meaning of "multiple" target rules in GNU Make manual, includes 0 - however this is poorly documented)

```
SOURCES := \
    a.src \
    b.src \
    c.src

OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:src=bin)

OBJECT := $(firstword $(OBJECTS))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJECTS)

$(subst $(OBJECT),, $(OBJECTS)): $(OBJECT)

$(OBJECT): $(SOURCES) Makefile
    compiler .

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```